# Sent mail from php goes into spam folder

Tags: php, email, header, sendmail

I used this tutorial for sending mail :

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

My code looks like this :

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: The Sender <senter@sender.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" 
mail("recipient@recipient.com", "Message", "A simple message.", $headers);
```

> I am using localhost(MAMP PRO) for sending mail.

But mail goes to spam folder.How to send mail which goes to inbox.Please guys help me out from this,i spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: create a spf record for your domain

Comment: @DevZer0 : I am using localhost(MAMP PRO) for sending mail.

Answer (score 1):

Which folder an email goes into depends mostly on the domain & ipaddress from which the email is coming from and the email service provider. If your domain/ip is trusted by the service provider it will not be spammed.
Also, after setting a few emails as "Not Spam" from that domain, your email service will no longer spam the emails

Comment: I am using localhost(MAMP PRO) for sending mail.

Comment: That's why. localhost emails are always spammed from my experience. It should work properly when you upload the code on the web hosting server :)

Comment: That's the way it always works for me, and I have done lots of custom emailing scripts

Answer (score 0):

there are more than one reason ur email goes to spam ... 
1 - make sure that the "from email" is actually the email u are sending the emails from .. i mean dont use any other false "from Email"

2- you have to keep the message body simple as possible . dont use so much html tags and css experssions , and also try to use tables